# Sequelize Association : same field with multiple table is possible?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have the following four models

**User**

```
user_id
user_email
```

**Permit**

```
permit_id
permit_name
```

**Label**

```
label_id
label_name
module_name   (user or permit)
```

**ModuleLabel**

```
module_label_id  
label_id   **(fk - Label table)**
module_id  (user_id or permit_id)
```

**How can I get mapped Label details while fetching permit data using sequelize?**

**Select "from" Permit, join ModuleLabel where module_id=permit_id && module_name = 'permit'(from Label table), and then join Label from there**

Comment: is there any foreign key relation between these tables?

Comment: @AtulAgrawal : updated question

Comment: Any progress here?

Answer (score 2):

It can be done but definitely without constraints in the database. In your case the `module_id` field in `ModuleLabel` may reference `user` or `permit` table. I can show you some implementation sketch, however I would suggest reconstructing the schema e.g. create `UserLabel` and `PermitLabel` models which would have foreign key constraint to `User` and `Permit`. However, below is how you can do it your way

```
// in User model definition
classMethods: {
    associate: function(models){
        this.hasMany(models.ModuleLabel, { foreignKey: 'module_id', constraints: false });
    }
}

// in Permit model definition
classMethods: {
    associate: function(models){
        this.hasMany(models.ModuleLabel, { foreignKey: 'module_id', constraints: false });
    }
}
```

Above associations allow us to join `ModuleLabel` model when querying both `User` or `Permit`. The most important part is to remember about the `constraints: false` which prevents creating database constraints. Let's move on. The `Label` model does not need any associations, only fields declaration. The last model is `ModuleLabel`

```
// in ModuleLabel model definition
classMethods: {
    associate: function(models){
        this.belongsTo(models.Label, { foreignKey: 'label_id' });
        this.belongsTo(models.User, { foreignKey: 'module_id', constraints: false });
        this.belongsTo(models.Permit, { foreignKey: 'module_id', constraints: false });
    }
}
```

Now, in order to perform your desired query, you can do this

```
models.Permit.findAll({
    include: [
        {
            model: models.ModuleLabel,
            include: [
                {
                    model: models.Label,
                    where: { module_name: 'permit' }
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}).then((result) => {
    console.log(result);
});
```

Above query would generate SQL similar to this presented below

```sql
SELECT * FROM Permits
LEFT OUTER JOIN ModuleLabels
ON Permits.id = ModuleLabels.module_id
INNER JOIN Labels
ON ModuleLabels.label_id = Labels.id
AND Label.module_name = 'permit';
```

Answer (score 0):

From your description it seems you're trying to select "from" `Permit`, join `ModuleLabel` where `module_id=permit_id`, and then join `Label` from there. If that's not correct, please clarify the question.

If that's the case, what you want to do is absolutely possible by setting up `hasMany` relationships. However, I advise against re-using key fields in generic ways like this (where `module_id` could be either a permit or user ID). I've personally spent a lot of time working with raw Entity tables in Drupal, which do the same thing - an ID could map to any number of foreign tables, and you had to evaluate each record's type to know which one to join. It made for very messy and big queries and was confusing to debug in a hurry if something got corrupted. (And easy to make mistakes.)

Comment: Updated question
"Select "from" Permit, join ModuleLabel where module_id=permit_id && module_name = 'permit'(from Label table), and then join Label from there"